# Input changes border based on its value

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, input

There is an input which accepts numerical values. If the value is greater than 10 it should change its border color to red and also show a tooltip with a text "value is too big".

This is the input:

```
<input className="my-input" type="number" />
```

I don't know how to connect the input value to css, I've made it turn the border red when the cursor is inside the input (:focus):

```
input:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline: none;
}
```

But how can it be done to change the border color when the input values is greater than 10? and also to show a tooltip when its happening

Comment: Do you know Javascript?

Comment: yes, but I don't want to use jQuery if possible

Comment: Firefox does this for you (at least on the version I have on Windows10) if you set min and max values in your input element. Other browsers do something similar - e.g. Edge/Chrome show a tooltip but they don't outline the element in red  in the versions I have

Comment: `<input type='number' min='0' max='10' value='0' />` should work with no JavaScript. At least it did in Firefox. I personally don't like the `box-shadow` so I set it to `box-shadow:none;` and control that behavior with JavaScript *(by setting CSS classes)*, myself, but do as you wish.

Comment: @StackSlave in your case I wouldn't be able to write a value greater than 10. I want to be able to do that and in that case to change the border color

Answer (score 1):

This is where JavaScript comes to the rescue, what you should do is the following:

- Create a css class to indicate the error style for the input.
- listen to value change of the input and add the error css class when
  value is superior than 10.

It's very simple:

```js
    function isValid(value) {
      return parseInt(value) <= 10;
    }

    // "input-error" is the css class for error
    const cssErrorClass = "input-error"
    function oninputchange(ev) {
      if(!isValid(ev.target.value)) {
        ev.target.classList.add(cssErrorClass)
      }
      else if(ev.target.classList.contains(cssErrorClass)) {
        ev.target.classList.remove(cssErrorClass);
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("my-input").onkeyup = oninputchange;
    document.getElementById("my-input").onchange = oninputchange;
```

```css
.input-error {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
    <input id="my-input" type="number" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try below which works on most modern browsers.

```css
input:focus:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" max="10" />
```

Comment: in this case you cannot write a value greater than 9. but this doesn't solve my requirement. in my case the user must be able to write any value and if the value is greater 10 it should be warned by changing the border to red

Comment: pretty sure you can. try running the code snippet :) `max` just validates the input